# Defining fuzzy properties of crisp graphs

Tags: graph-theory, fuzziness

> Is there a standard procedure to
>   define fuzzy generalizations of
>   typical graph properties?

Consider the concept of a *fuzzy clique*. Define the *cliqueness* $c(G)$ of a graph $G$ as the ratio $\text{deg}(G)\ /\ (|V(G)|-1)$ between the mean degree of $G$ and the number of its vertices (minus one).

Alternatively: $c(G) = 2\ |E|\ /\ (|V|^2 - |V|)$.

That is, a graph deviates from being a "true" clique with the number of its missing possible edges. But shouldn't the missing edges been distributed as uniformly as possible among the vertices? Isn't **3** more of a (fuzzy) clique than **2** (which is more of a "true" clique plus an extra vertex), even though they have the same *cliqueness*?

[image][(source)](http://epublius.de/mathoverflow/fuzzy4.png)

Should one try to capture this (felt) difference between **2** and **3**? E.g. by considering higher moments of the distribution of missing edges?

> Is this program (including higher moments) executed somewhere?
>   And how is it to be generalized?

Comment: Which graph properties are of this kind: to be understood as an X-ness? Connected-ness? Tree-ness? Circle-ness?

Comment: I agree with Felix. Spectral graph theory is almost certainly the sort of thing you want, since eigenvalues and other linear algebra things tend to be the most well-behaved fuzzy measurements. For instance, I think that connectedness is algebraic connectivity.

Comment: Cliqueness might be algebraic connectivity, divided by vertices minus one?

Answer (score 1):

I think fractional graph theory fits the bill...

Also, spectral extremal graph theory might be interesting. There is a new and excellent survey by Nikiforov:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1121.pdf

Answer (score 1):

One way to argue that 2 has more cliqueness than 3 is to take whatever graph clustering algorithm you like, and ask whether or not the graph ends up as one cluster.  Likely 2 will be split into two clusters, whereas 3 will be one cluster, but this depends on the algorithm.

The issue is discussed in Chapter 2 of my master's thesis (http://www.sfu.ca/~adk7/papers/mscthesis.ps) but it's eight years old and probably not the best reference out there.

Comment: As an empirical investigation, this might be great, but I'm not sure an informative theoretical measure can be had this way.

Comment: Agreed.  The problem of how to find a good graph clustering is subject to a lot of debate, and is very closely related to this problem.  Given a clustering scoring function $f$, and letting $f_o$ be the optimal score of any clustering (vertex partition) of $G$, probably $f_o/f(G)$ would be a good measurement of cliqueness.  But in the end, finding the function $f$ is really a matter of taste and context.